# Javascript function inside polymer is not a function error

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, vaadin-flow

I have a javascript function defined in polymer as such:
`myTest(arg) {<do stuff here>}`

Inside this function, based on some conditions, I want to change the `onclick` of a button defined in the polymer template to some other function. For this I'm doing `document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {myTest('someArg')};`

The problem I'm having is that when the above line gets invoked I'm getting an error

> Uncaught TypeError: myTest is not a function.

If I try to use the function keyword when declaring the function the compiler complains with

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

What's the correct syntax to for changing the button's onclick function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the the full source code example, but it sounds like the problem you're facing is related to JavaScript not inferring `this` as the context for calling instance methods in the same way that e.g. Java does. To make things more complicated, `this` wouldn't have the expected value inside the `function` that you create for the click listener.

One way around that would be to use an arrow function since they aren't redefining the execution context:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = () => { this.myTest('someArg') };
```

Another alternative is to explicitly capture `this` into a separate variable and then use that variable inside the function:

```
var self = this;
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() { self.myTest('someArg') };
```